Isekai manga where the main character has the power to cut anything he believes he can cut
It is an isekai that started with a class being summoned to another world where the woman were used to blackmail the man and the main character has the power to cut anything he believes he can cut.

"the woman were used to blackmail the man" Did you mean, where the women were used to blackmail the men? And how did the main character cut things? With a sword?

@LogicDictates - His acerbic wit, perhaps?

Could this be I Was Summoned to Another World, but I Got the Power to Cut Anything, so It Was Easy Mode?
The main character states that he can cut everything he believes he can cut.

The chancellor is a Class-A bastard and uses the female students to blackmail the male characters into fighting monsters.

I should warn potential readers that while the story itself is a fairly humdrum isekai, at the end of each chapter it becomes badly-written porno where all the (high-school-aged) woman are willing sex slaves.
